# Inserting actual hours (not time) to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert actual hours not the time itself to MySQL database through form fields. So for example

```
$time1 = '00:00';
$time2 = '27:20';
$time3 = '00:45';
```

So I can retrieve the different rows and can calculate on the fly whenever require. Either through search query or even in other area of the system.

When I have tried to do addition of above three times, it is not giving the result the way I am looking for

```
$total = strtotime($time1) + strtotime($time2) + strtotime($time3);
echo date('H:i:s', $total);
```

The result

```
14:16:44
```

While it should be something like

```
28:05:00
```

I have used `TIME` DATATYPE in MySQL table. I may use as a TEXT but I am also concern about the error happen in user input. Where I do not have to force the user to insert the any particular format but they can either insert as below way

```
27.20
27:20
```

or

```
1.5
1:30
```

My main concern is to calculate the time, the user input can be on second priority but it would be great if can implement.

So is there anyway, idea or hint to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in the hours and minutes, why don't you just store the value as an in integer? Just multiply the hours by 60.

You can handle the conversion in PHP.

Alternatively, you can also easily use two (very small) int fields for this.

Comment: This could be good idea too. Just one question. If I use integer than how can I handle the decimal value. like 1:30 or 27:45 etc? or `FLOAT` or even `TEXT` could work as well?

Comment: Read my message again. If you are only interested in the hours and minutes, multiply hours by 60. So `1:30` would translate to `1 * 60 + 30 = 90 minutes`.

Comment: Oh! I got what you mean. This could be great idea. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[`date()`](http://php.net/date) expects the timestamp in UNIX format, i.e. seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC (which is also the value provided by [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime))

You're passing it the result of adding a series of amounts of time since 1 January 1970 instead of just adding up hours, so (as far as `date` is concerned) you're generating a random date and time, and printing only the time (try printing the date of `$total` and see what you get).

Since your time is stored in the database, one possibility is to let MySQL handle the time calculations itself, e.g.:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('00:00',ADDTIME('27:20','00:45'))
```

will result in "28:05:00". You can have your database fields as `TIME` and operate on them directly through SQL, and do the user input conversions into acceptable `TIME` values in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for providing nice details. Just to clarify that here `00:00` is not the time but it is the amount of hours. Means there is `0` hours. So will your idea work with this value too?

Comment: @CodeLover i can't see the difference, but yes, 00:00 will be interpreted as zero hours

Comment: Cool.. Let me try it now and get back to you. Thanks